# Magic Line CSS/Javascript code - Adding sub navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am implementing this "Magic Line" code into my navigation menu, but I seem to be having troubles when adding a sub menu. When you hover over any sub menu items, the magic line shoots all the way to the left side of the page. I would like it to stay on the menu item that the submenus are under.

You can view my site here: http://www.christmaslightsinstallation.ca/

Original script (without sub nav): http://css-tricks.com/examples/MagicLine/

(I tried a fiddle for this, but since it's in wordpress it wasn't translating very well)

**My javascript is as follows:**

```
$(function() {

var $el, leftPos, newWidth,
    $mainNav = $("#menu-main-menu");

$testing = $(".menu-header");

$testing.append("<span id='magic-line'></span>");
var $magicLine = $("#magic-line");

$magicLine
    .width($(".current_page_item").width())
    .css("left", $(".current_page_item a").position().left)
    .data("origLeft", $magicLine.position().left)
    .data("origWidth", $magicLine.width());

$("#menu-main-menu li a").hover(function() {
    $el = $(this);
    leftPos = $el.position().left;
    newWidth = $el.parent().width();
    $magicLine.stop().animate({
        left: leftPos,
        width: newWidth
    });
}, function() {
    $magicLine.stop().animate({
        left: $magicLine.data("origLeft"),
        width: $magicLine.data("origWidth")
    });    
});
});
```

I tried creating a second hover function using "#menu-main-menu li li a", and trying to use a "preventdefault();" event. Which just caused a ton of errors.

I'm fairly new to javascript, so limited on things I can think of/know how to do, to try a fix for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$("#menu-main-menu li a").hover(function() {`

Change the above line to:

`$("#menu-main-menu > li").hover(function() {`

**Edit:**

Also change:

```
newWidth = $el.parent().width();
```

to:

```
newWidth = $el.width();
```

Comment: Thanks @Coby That mostly works. Now the only thing is when you hover over something the magic line takes up the entire width of the navbar rather than just the li width. I could manually type a width, but is there a dynamic way to do it?

Comment: Oy! Sorry, just saw something else...when you are on a sub page, and try and use the navigation the magic bar comes all the way from the left. Not a huge deal, but... http://www.christmaslightsinstallation.ca/about-us/our-lights/